# Scaling in Homogenous coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-vision

I am reading Forsythe and Ponce (Computer Vision) and it says:
"We will use the convention that homogeneous coordinates are only defined up to scale, whether they represent points or planes."
I want to know what does "up to scale" means in the above statement.
I'm a newbie to homogeneous coordinates, so please answer in simple English.
I also saw this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114880/up-to-a-scale-factor
But I didn't get it, so if anyone can elaborate, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

One should think of projective space as "all lines through the origin.

So, in general, given a line $y= \lambda x$ (where $x \neq 0$), we think of these as a single point in space. In other words, we make the identification $(x,y) \sim(\lambda x, \lambda y)$, where $\lambda \neq 0$, since these two determine the same line (i.e the line is determined by its slope, so $y/x=\lambda y/\lambda x$) so in homogeneous co-ordinates,

$$[x,y]=[\lambda x, \lambda y],$$

for any scalar $\lambda \neq 0$.

The real point here is that the equivalence relation $\sim$ is one way to represent all lines through the plane. If you would really like to see this in a hands on way, pick a "representative" for the equivalence relation.

One way to do this is to select the line $x=1$ and each line that is not the line $x=0$ will intersect this vertical line in one unique place. Choose these points to be your representatives, and then it will become clear that any line that differs from another by a scalar $\lambda$ will have the same point as its representative.

Comment: I still don't get it. If you can explain it to me in a more intuitive way, perhaps that can help. If you can explain it to me using a real world example (like projection of 3d world on a computer screen by a camera), that's even better.

Comment: @user3033326 you can do some things like that (projective transformations i.e homographies) but I think that's more difficult than just understanding homogeneous co-ordinates. The intuitive way, is literally, to identify points up to scalars. If you are familiar with the language of linear algebra, you can think of each point as the span of a single vector $[a,b]$, so that $k[a,b] \sim [a,b]$ for all scalars $k$.